# Sort month column in chronological order

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a meta data column which has months( January, February,..., December). I need to sort it in chronological order (January, February,..., December) but on sorting it gets sorted in alphabetical order. I need to sort the  metadata month column in chronological order without using calculated column. Please suggest me some better ways to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure custom sort order for the term set.

1. Go to the site where you want to custom sort terms (if you are updating a local term set).
2. On the **Site Actions** menu, click **Site Settings**.
3. Under **Site Administration**, click **Term Store management**.
4. In the **Properties** pane, select the Managed Metadata Service application you want, if it is not already selected.
5. In the tree view pane on the left, expand the groups to find the term set that you want, and then select the term set.
6. In the pane on the right, click the **Custom Sort** tab.
7. Under **Custom Sort Order**, select **Use custom sort order**.
8. Click the arrows in the boxes next to the terms to reorder the terms in the sequence that you want.
9. Click **Save**.

   [image]

After changing the sort order, if you have already created a metadata column in the list/library, edit this column without any changes to refresh it. Then, you will find the terms are in the order as you want.

[image]

If you want to sort items by on month metadata column in chronological order in a list view, you'd better name month with prefix, like "01.January, 02.February, 03.March". By default, SharePoint only sort items by column in ascending (A,B,c or 1,2,3) or descending (C,B,A or 3,2,1) order.

Comment: Even 1.January, 2.February will not sort correctly, because it will sort 10.October and 11.November and 12.December before 2.February, since these are strings and the sort is alphabetic.

Comment: can use double value

Answer (score 0):

Who don't you want to use an extra calculated column? That is by far the easiest way to go. In fact, I cannot think of another way at all.

You don't have to include the helper column in the view, you only need it for the sort. Without that, the values are just text and will always be sorted alphabetically. If you want a different sort order, you will need to use a different column to sort on.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the Term Storm Management option above but if that is too complicated for you I agree that the calculated column works perfectly and is much easier to set up.  I always start out in Excel to work out a calculation because it translates well to SharePoint. I have a choice field for users to select the month called "Month".  I then created a calculated field "MS" and sort based on Year and MS.  Here is my calculation for MS: =IF([Month]="January",1,(IF([Month]="February",2,(IF([Month]="March",3,(IF([Month]="April",4,(IF([Month]="May",5,(IF([Month]="June",6,(IF([Month]="July",7,(IF([Month]="August",8,(IF([Month]="September",9,(IF([Month]="October",10,(IF([Month]="November",11,(IF([Month]="December",12,0)))))))))))))))))))))))